# Windows8 Metro app resolution detection issue C#

Tags: c#

I have a question that,In metro application, how the app detect that on which resolution of display install it.
Please help.

Comment: Use the Bounds property of your Window.

Answer (score 0):

When installing, you cannot detect anything.

You can detect resolution when app is running, which is clear. One can change resolution after installing your app.

I use following code:

```
  Size renderSize = Window.Current.Content.RenderSize;
  var resolution = renderSize;
```

Make sure Window.Current.Content is not null.